# sockets acting weird in combination with threadpoolexecutor

Tags: java, sockets

I have a really confusing situation here. I have two sides (client/server) and try to send data between them via sockets/objectoutputstream/objectinputstream. I have something like this:

SERVER:

```
public static void main (String[] a){
    ThreadPoolExecutor transactionThreadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNum);
    serverSocket.setSoTimeout(Constants.CONTROL_SERVERSOCKET_SOTIMEOUT);
    while (true){
      try {
        transactionThreadPoolExecutor.submit(new Transaction(dataSource, serverSocket.accept()));
      }catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("default Socket Timeout reached!", getClass());
      }
    }
}
```

TRANSACTION implements Runnable:

```
...
public Transaction(ConduitDataSource source, Socket socket){
...
    Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ")opening on port: " + socket.getLocalPort() + "...", getClass());
...
}
...
@Override
    public void run() {
        Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") running!", getClass());
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        ObjectInputStream objectInput = null;
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = null;
        try {
            Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") creating inputstream...", getClass());
            input = socket.getInputStream();
            Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") creating outputstream...", getClass());
            output = socket.getOutputStream();
            Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") creating objectInputstream...", getClass());
            objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(input);
            Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") creating objectOutputstream...", getClass());
            objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
            Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") stream's ready. reading transaction id...", getClass());
            transactionId = 02.10.23-04:23:55@com.ffleuchten.conduit.peripheral.utils.ConduitConnector: (18801883-15c9-457f-960d-17a57c4e97ee)objectoutputstream created: java.io.ObjectOutputStream@7de62196(UUID) objectInput.readObject();
            Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") stream's ready. reading transaction type...", getClass());
            transactionType = objectInput.readByte();
            Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") reading transaction params...", getClass());
            parameters = (Map<String, Object>)objectInput.readObject();
            Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") reading transaction expected fields...", getClass());
            fields = (List<String>)objectInput.readObject();
            ResultSet result = null;
            Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") TransactionType: " + transactionType, getClass());
            switch(transactionType) {
...
        Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") writing result: " + result, getClass());
        objectOutput.writeObject(result);
        objectOutput.flush();
        Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("Transaction (" + this.toString() + ") transaction complete!", getClass());
```

CLIENT:

```
...
Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("(" + transactionId + ")opening socket connection to " + Constants.getGatewayHostAddress() + "@" + port, ConduitConnector.class);
socket = new Socket(Constants.getGatewayHostAddress(), port);
Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("(" + transactionId + ")socket created!", java.io.ObjectOutputStream@7de62196or.class);
output = socket.getOutputStream();
Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("(" + transactionId + ")outputstream created:" + output, ConduitConnector.class);
input = socket.getInputStream();
Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("(" + transactionId + ")inputstream created: " + input, ConduitConnector.class);
objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("(" + transactionId + ")objectoutputstream created: " + objectOutput, ConduitConnector.class);
objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(input);
Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("(" + transactionId + ")objectinputstream created: " + objectInput, ConduitConnector.class);
Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("(" + transactionId + ")waiting for transaction response...", ConduitConnector.class);
result = (ResultSet) objectInput.readObject();
Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("(" + transactionId + ")transaction complete!", ConduitConnector.class);
    ...
```

So basically what should happen is, that every time the client opens a connection it should start a new thread at serverside handling the communication via the Transaction class.
But it gets stuck on creating the objectinputstream.

According to the log files, the last line on the Server side is:

```
02.10.23-04:23:55@com.ffleuchten.conduit.core.Transaction: Transaction (TRANSACTION(null):undefined))opening on port: 33209...
```

So this states it is in the constructor of the Transaction class and should proceed with running the run() method. But it never does. The Client side get's stuck where last log line is:

```
02.10.23-04:23:55@com.ffleuchten.conduit.peripheral.utils.ConduitConnector: (18801883-15c9-457f-960d-17a57c4e97ee)objectoutputstream created: java.io.ObjectOutputStream@7de62196
```

which tells me, that it is right before creating the objectinputstream, which it never does.

Funny thing is: 45 transactions are handled correct(counting the transaction complete lines in the log). But the 46th transaction get's stuck. btw: all the transactions do the same on server side.

So what's happening here? Does anyone has any suggestions on why this is happening? It feels like the treadpoolexecutor never executes the Transaction run method. But if so, why does the client get stuck on creating the objectinputstream then? shouldn't it stop when client is trying to receive data from the (not executing) server side?
I am out of ideas about this one. Any help is highly appreciated ;)

as mentioned in the comments I added some status info about the threadpoolexecutor to the logs. I can now see, that it should be fine before it get's stuck(at the same position as always, before creating the objectinputstream):

```
02.10.23-05:20:26@com.ffleuchten.conduit.core.Conduit: conduit listening on port: 40423...
02.10.23-05:20:26@com.ffleuchten.conduit.core.Conduit: threadpool active count: 0...
02.10.23-05:20:26@com.ffleuchten.conduit.core.Conduit: threadpool completed task count: 41...
02.10.23-05:20:26@com.ffleuchten.conduit.core.Conduit: threadpool task count: 42...
02.10.23-05:20:26@com.ffleuchten.conduit.core.Conduit: threadpool queue size: 1...
02.10.23-05:20:26@com.ffleuchten.conduit.core.Transaction: Transaction (TRANSACTION(null):undefined)) running!
02.10.23-05:20:26@com.ffleuchten.conduit.core.Transaction: Transaction (TRANSACTION(null):undefined)) creating inputstream...
02.10.23-05:20:26@com.ffleuchten.conduit.core.Transaction: Transaction (TRANSACTION(null):undefined)) creating outputstream...
02.10.23-05:20:26@com.ffleuchten.conduit.core.Transaction: Transaction (TRANSACTION(null):undefined)) creating objectInputstream...
```

Comment: With only 8 threads in a thread pool, it's possible that you just run out of threads.  Once all threads are in use, there aren't any more.  Could you arrange to dump the state of the thread pool, so we can see where all the threads are executing?  A debugger might help with this, as they can do that dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am starting to believe that as well. But everytime the transaction completes, the Thread should be done => closed? Do i have to free threadpool resources manually? I'll try to get state info about the threadpool. might take a sec... ;)

Comment: Just added stateinfo to the log, but it seems as there should be plenty of available threads, as the active count is zero when running into stuckness.

Comment: Note that `new ObjectInputStream(input)` and `new ObjectOutputStream(output)` calls cause read and write to the underlying stream, so will block if the other side of the communication isn't processing. You haven't shown enough code of client + server to tell, nor stack traces which might help.

Comment: Please provide code in the question as a [mre]. Otherwise, all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't provide the neede minimal reproducible example, as it is part of a bigger framework. I am fine with just guesses, which I can invest on further. I have done some further research now and it looks like the thread just stops executing in the middle of the code (everytime on a different line). It does not throw any Throwable and just stops. I've already increased the usabel cores/threads on the machine, but no difference. The code just stops running. Never have seen this behaviour before.

Comment: You must create the object output stream before the object input stream, at both ends. Otherwise you can get a deadlock. It has nothing to to with the executor.

Comment: @user207421 you've seen my answer below?

Comment: Sure. Doesn't change what I said. Seen it many times. @DuncG said the same thing, also correct. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out: the thread on serverside did some printing to stdout (good old System.out.println) and apparentely if you start a java process via

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

, which the server side started like, then there seems to be a limit to what can be printed to stdout? So after a while it just stopped running on the printout line. Found this with the jstack tool and after removing the "logging" to stdout completely all went through without issues :) So after all there was never an issue with the socket connection, just some weirdness when running a java process via java and using System.out.println...

Comment: No weirdness. If your process produces output you should use `Process` and consume its output and error streams.

Comment: weirdness in the sense, that it just halts the program and does not produce any exception/error by doing so. I would have expected to get a BufferOverflowException or something like that. But TIL I guess :D

Comment: If you use `Process` incorrectly the behaviour is no different to someone accidentally using "Ctrl-S" in a terminal - the program pauses indefinitely when writing next message (applies to any binary not just Java). There are many questions such as [getRuntime(): getting output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program) and [Runtime exec Process hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64440436/runtime-exec-process-hangs/64447618#64447618). Note that the accepted answer in the first question ISN'T safe to use.

Comment: Of course I used it "incorrectly" as I did not know abaout this issue and do not care about Sysouts in this case. But as always I learned something today ;)

Comment: @roediGERhard Sorry I've worded my comment badly, I should have started with "If Process is used incorrectly ...". It is a very common issue to find with Runtime.exec / ProcessBuilder.